# GAE - php5.5 - The PHP runtime is not available

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I am trying to run a helloworld gae php program locally, but get error when I start the server.

My environment:

`linux mint mate 17` `php5.5` `php-cgi5.5` `python2.7.6` `gae_php_1.9.17`

The error info I get when try to start web server in gae locally:

```
INFO     2015-02-08 16:17:32,197 api_server.py:172] Starting API server at: http://localhost:54892
INFO     2015-02-08 16:17:32,201 dispatcher.py:186] Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2015-02-08 16:17:32,202 admin_server.py:118] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
ERROR    2015-02-08 16:17:33,204 php_runtime.py:227] The PHP runtime is not available
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/star/program/gae/gae_php_1.9.17/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/php_runtime.py", line 223, in new_instance
    self._runtime_config_getter().application_root)
  File "/mnt/star/program/gae/gae_php_1.9.17/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/php_runtime.py", line 148, in _check_environment
    'flag (%s) does not exist.' % php_executable_path)
_PHPBinaryError: The path specified with the --php_executable_path flag () does not exist.
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you're not passing `--php_executable_path` (it's showing up as an empty string, its default).  Running:

```
dev_appserver.py --php_executable_path=/usr/bin/php-cgi yourapp
```

may therefore work better for you.

Comment: It worked, but why it can't find the php-cgi by itself? the gae document didn't use the param.

Comment: @EricWang, see https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/tools/devserver.  On both Mac and Windows the GAE SDK includes a PHP 5.4 which is OK for many (but not all) development setups, so that's the default one -- `php_executable_path` is a way to override the default specifying another PHP (maybe a 5.5, or a 5.4 built w/mcrypt and gd, etc, etc).  Moreover there is no single standard way, across all PHP versions and platforms, to find out which executable (if any) is the **CGI** version, which GAE needs, rather than the command-line one.